# In twig template run php code

Tags: php, twig

Is it possible to make twig function rendered as php-code, as I need to exit current template, something like this:

```
{% if HostelsList|length == 0  %}
    {# <div>No Data Found.&nbsp;</div> #}
    {{ make_return() }} {# |raw #}
{% endif %}
```

and function definition:

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('make_return', function () {
    echo '<pre>make return</pre>'; // I see this output
    return '<?php echo "ZZZZZ"; return; ?>';  // I DO NOT see this output and flow is not stopped rendering...
} , array('is_safe' => array('all' ) );
$this->m_twig_Environment->addFunction($function);
```

Also i tried to use `|raw` in 1st statement, but failed. Which is the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish? Why don't u place everything else in the `{% else %} ..... {% endif %}` block? EDIT : twig renders it's templates as PHP, turn on caching and see what twig makes out of your atempt to exit the script

Answer (score 1):

I review twig rendered files and see lines like :

```
// line 8
if ((twig_length_filter($this->env, (isset($context["HostelsList"]) ? $context["HostelsList"] : null)) == 0)) {
    // line 9
    echo "            ";
    // line 10
    echo "            <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block\">No Data Found</button>
    <a style=\"margin-top: -5px;\" href=\"";
    // line 11
    echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, (isset($context["base_url"]) ? $context["base_url"] : null), "html", null, true);
    echo "admin/hostel/hostelstep1\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right\">New Hostel</a>
    ";
    // line 13
    echo "            ";
    echo call_user_func_array($this->env->getFunction('make_return')->getCallable(), array());
    echo "
";
}
// line 15
```

no return php code.

Sure i can use  {% else %} ..... {% endif %} block, but I would prefer to find other decision.

In smarty I defined "return" construction, like :

```
{if count($ToursList) eq 0}
    <div>No Data Found.&nbsp;</div>
    <a class="grey" href="admin/tour/tourstep1">New Tour</a>
    {return}
{/if}
```

That was helpfull, as I prefer not to create  {else} ..... {endif} big blocks, especially if template is big in size.

If smarty has some exit(template) constructions or is it possible to define them in some other way ?

Thanks!